# AndroidJunit4 doesn't accept space function test name?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-instrumentation, android-runtime, android-junit

I have the following test, where the test name is with space and backtick for my instrumental test

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MyTestClass {
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var activityRule: ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    @Test
    fun `My space name testing`() {
          // Some test
    }
}
```

However when running it, it can't be executed (i.e. No test were found)

Checking on it, I saw this linting error on the test function name..

`This inspection reports identifiers in android projects which are not accepted by the Android runtime (for example, method names containing spaces)`

When I rename my test function from `My space name testing` to `mySpaceNameTesting`, the test run.

Is it really that AndroidJunit4 runtime can't support test function name with spaces?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Correct, it's unsupported in the Android runtime. See the [Coding Conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#naming-rules) page here. Specifically:

> In tests (and only in tests), it's acceptable to use method names with
>   spaces enclosed in backticks. (Note that such method names are
>   currently not supported by the Android runtime.) Underscores in method
>   names are also allowed in test code.

Comment: Seems to have been addressed if you target API 30: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/ab5f4c17a86b8c808dba862db566f0ffa1146367

Comment: I'm targeting API 31 and it doesn't work yet. Could it be because the Android Gradle Plugin in IntelliJ IDEA is older than the one in Android Studio?

Comment: Seems you have to set minSdkVersion 30+